# Save TAGS File in Emacs Root Project

Tags: emacs, tags, etags

How to save `TAGS` file JUST in root of project?

My emacs config will save `TAGS` file in each directory when I change a file.
For example when I change a file in `src/` directory, it will save a `TAGS` file in this directory instead of saving this file in root of the project:

```
project1:
  main.py
  TAGS          <<< correct.
  src/
      newlib.py
      TAGS      <<< incorrect. this file should be store in root directory (project1/TAGS)
  libs/
      something.py
```

This is my emacs config for `TAGS`:

```
;; create tags
(defun create-tags (dir-name)
  "Create tags file."
  (interactive "DDirectory: ")
    (eshell-command
      (format "find . -type f -iname \"*.py\" -not -path \"*/venv/*\" | etags -" dir-name)))

;; refresh tags
(defun er-refresh-etags (&optional extension)
  "Run etags on all peer files in current dir and reload them silently."
  (interactive)
    (shell-command (format "find . -type f -iname \"*.py\" -not -path \"*/venv/*\" | etags -" '.))
    (let ((tags-revert-without-query t))  ; don't query, revert silently          
      (visit-tags-table default-directory nil)))

;; hooks for tags
(create-tags '.)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (create-tags '.))
(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'er-refresh-etags)
```

Comment: How will you identify "the root of the project"?  If you have no idea, then the function `locate-dominating-file` may help you.

Comment: @phils, currently just by putting `.` .

Comment: `.` means the current directory.

Comment: @phils, yes you are right. but I'm looking for a solution to fix this.

Comment: Also, your `create-tags` function doesn't actually use its argument.

Comment: No one can tell you how to identify the root of your project.  It's *your* project.  What reliably differentiates the root directory of your project from any of its sub-directories?

Comment: I'll add that many people find [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#readme) a useful way to manage projects, so that may be worth investigating. It includes some tags functionality of its own, but would also provide a common way to obtain a project's root (which looks to be the `projectile-project-root` function).